# Equivalent of Stata's expand in R

Tags: r, stata

Whilst reviewing a colleague's Stata code I came across the command `expand`.

I would really love to be able to do the same thing simply in my own R code.

Essentially `expand` duplicates a dataset n times but has the option to create a new variable which is 0 if the observation originally appeared
in the dataset and 1 if the observation is a duplicate.

Does anyone know of a quick way of implementing this in R? Or is it a case of writing my own function?

Comment: Look for `rep()` in `R`. But you might need to tweak it to get exact replica of the expand function of stata. If you could share a small sample of data and the expected output, you will surely get a better answer.

Comment: Good idea is to give accessible documentation for R users. https://www.stata.com/manuals/dexpand.pdf Many more will understand what this does from glancing at documentation than will know because they use Stata as well as R.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the edit, I'll be sure to add links in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rep_r<-function(x,n){if(n<=1){rep(x,times=1)}else{rep(x,times=n)}}

expand_r<-function(x,n){
    Reduce(function(x,y)
        {c(x,y)},mapply(rep_r,x,n))
}

expand_r(c(2,3,4,1,5),c(-1,0,1,2,3))
#[1] 2 3 4 1 1 5 5 5
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to the suggestion from **@nicola** the above functionality can be simply achieved by the following one-liner.

```
expand_r<-function(x,n) rep(x,replace(n,n<1,1))
#>expand_r(c(2,3,4,1,5),c(-1,0,1,2,3))
#[1] 2 3 4 1 1 5 5 5
```

Comment: No need of any `Reduce` and `mapply`, since also `rep` accepts a vector as the `times` argument. The only difference with stata seems to be how the less than 1 values are handled. So, a more efficient way of your function could be `expand_r<-function(x,n) rep(x,replace(n,n<1,1))`.

Comment: @nicola Thanks for the invaluable tip.

Answer (score 1):

This function expands the rows of a data.frame like the Stata `expand` command does.  I got the idea from the R `mefa` package.

```
expand_r <- function(df, ...) {
  as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, ...))
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c("a", "b"))

expand_r(df, times = 3)
```